# How to transfer code from old version of xcode to the newest verision?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an **xcode** project for an app i made a while ago but its on `xcode 3.2`, how can i easily transfer the project to the newer version of xcode?

I have tried manually transferring each file of the project to the new version but was not very successful with that.

Is there an easier/more automated way of doing this?

EDIT: Realized its from xcode 3.2, not 4

Comment: What was the problem in transferring files from old project to new project ? And depending upon your app type , you can open your old xcode project in the new xcode version easily. You dont need to do any extra work, just open your project in new xcode.

Comment: when i try to open the project file in the new xcode it says "file cannot be opened"

Comment: Sorry i made a typo, its from xcode 3.2, not 4

Answer (score 2):

Depends what type of app is it ? OpenGL game, normal app, what ? Please specify.

Xcode 4 apps won't have much difficulty being ported on Xcode 5 unless your app doesn't have Automatic Reference Counting.

Otherwise, just open the .xcodeproj file in the new version of Xcode and everything will happen automatically.

Comment: its a simple view based application, when i try to open the .xcodeproj file from the old xcode to the new one, it says the file "cannot be opened"

Comment: i just realized that im trying to open a xcode 3.2 file to the new one, does that make a difference?

Comment: The exact message it gives me is "The file couldn't be opened"