# Transferring code from old version of xcode to newer version

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode3to4

I have an xcode project for an app i made a while ago but its on xcode 3.2, how can i easily transfer the project to the newer version of xcode?

I have tried manually transferring each file of the project to the new version but was not very successful with that.

Is there an easier/more automated way of doing this?

Comment: You already asked the exact same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798958/how-to-transfer-code-from-old-version-of-xcode-to-the-newest-verision).

Comment: I know but i didn't get any helpful answers, hopefully this time around i will

Comment: Just open the xcproject file in the new xcode?